# APDEX - Is there any new approach so far?

Tags: response-time

Apdex is the application performance index that takes user's response times and classify them as "satisfied", "tolerable" or "frustrated". It is a simple approach to evaluate the user experience for business applications. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apdex) is described what the Apdex exactly is.

My question: Has anyone of you heard about a new approach how to measure an application's performance? I read on several websites that the Apdex is already outdated. Do you know of newer/better approaches to measure user expectations?

Answer (score 2):

Newrelic is a monitoring tool for web applications. They are using apdex as one of the primary measures but they also use "throughput" and etc. It has a 1 month pro subscription trial where you can see all the measures. I am on a standard subscription currenty, maybe you can discover more measures in pro subscription trial. Worth checking out :)

Hope I understood your question.